# How to install docker specific version

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, lxc-docker

How to install specific version of Docker(like `1.3.2`)?

I am unable to find any documentation in docker official docs.
Referring [this link for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/).

Following instructions install docker version `1.0.1`:

`$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install docker.io`

Also, following instructions install latest version of docker `1.4.1`:

`$ sudo sh -c "echo deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install lxc-docker`

How can I install specific version like `1.3.2`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Got the answer from this github [`issue comment`](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9697#issuecomment-67232206).

Summary of above commit:-

```
echo deb http://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9

apt-get update
apt-get install -y lxc-docker-1.3.3
```

If permission issue then use `sudo` as:

```
echo deb http://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y lxc-docker-1.3.3
```

**Bonus Tip:**

Don't know which version? Then hit `Tab` after `lxc-docker-` as:

```
sudo apt-get install -y lxc-docker-<Hit Tab here>
```

to see list of available docker versions.

Comment: it should be rather `echo deb http://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` for the permission issue

Comment: It only has docker version up to 1.9.1, any update to this?

Answer (score 34):

I find easier to check available versions with

```
sudo apt-cache policy docker-engine
```

and then install the one you want:

```
sudo  apt-get install docker-engine=1.7.1-0~trusty
```

It consists on simply following the instructions from docker docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/, but selecting a particular version

Comment: available version checking is very helpfull thank you

Comment: This should be the answer. Most concise and simpile.

Answer (score 17):

How I did it on my laptop (btw https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ not available anymore):

```
$ wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh      # install resources
$ apt-cache showpkg docker-engine             # show version which are available
$ apt-get install docker-engine=1.8.2-0~willy # install 1.8.2 version
$ sudo apt-mark hold docker-engine            # prevent upgrade on sys upgrade
$ docker version                              # check installed docker version
```

Answer (score 6):

Follow below step to install specific version of docker-ce and docker-ce-cli .

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update
```

Find the specific version of docker-ec and docker-ce-cli . Her in this example i am looking for 19.03

```
apt-cache policy docker-ce | grep 19
apt-cache policy docker-ce-cli | grep 19
```

From above command you will get list of docker version , copy respected version.

```
apt-get install docker-ce=5:19.03.14~3-0~ubuntu-bionic docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.14~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
```

Answer (score 2):

As Docker Introduces two different flavors (CE and EE) the best and easy way of installing Docker on any system. please run the below command and you do not have to do any thing.

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

if you want to install a specific version of a docker, you can run below command to find what all version of docker is present.

```
apt-cache madison docker-ce #(for ubuntu)
yum list docker-ce.x86_64  --showduplicates | sort -r #(for centos)
```

then select the proper version and place it in below command.

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sed 's/docker-ce/docker-ce=<DOCKER_VERSION/' | sh
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sed 's/lxc-docker/lxc-docker-1.6.2/' | sh
```

*Replace 1.6.2 with the version you want*.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to replace `install -y lxc-docker` in the script with `install -y lxc-docker-<version>`.

For example, this will install docker `1.6.2`:

```
RUN wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ | sed -r 's/^apt-get install -y lxc-docker$/apt-get install -y lxc-docker-1.6.2/g' | sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I got version 1.6.2 years old from source on Ubuntu 16.04. This might not translate to other Docker versions:

1. `git clone https://github.com/moby/moby docker`
2. `cd docker`
3. `git tag -l` -- find your tag of interest in this list (e.g. v1.6.2)
4. `git checkout <tag name>`
5. `sudo make build`

   Depending on how old your version is, you might see some errors in this step. If you see sample docker images failing to get pulled in, feel free to comment the associated lines out in the `Dockerfile`. You might see a `lvm2` source related failure. Modify the non-existent link to the source specified [here.](https://sourceware.org/lvm2/) Specifically, in my case, I had to change make `Dockerfile` refer to the `lvm2` source code at git at `git://sourceware.org/git/lvm2.git` .
6. `sudo make binary`