# How to mention specific version while installing docker on Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker, installation, raspberry-pi, version

I am trying to install `dockers` on `Raspberry pi` which is `arm` based device. Initially I used to run below command in order to install docker:

```
curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh
```

This install the latest version of dockers but I wanted to install an older version, which command should I use. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657888/how-to-install-docker-specific-version) have some useful answer but they are not working on `Raspberry pi`. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use below command to mention the version while installing the docker using `curl` command. I have tested this on `Raspberry pi` and it works fine so should also work fine on other linux based os.

```
export VERSION=18.03 && curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh
```

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256739/which-kubernetes-version-is-supported-in-docker-version-18-09/53257750#53257750)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you can't select the version using this method.  To do this, I use the following technique:

- Tell the Pi about the required repo

`echo "deb [arch=armhf] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`
`sudo apt update`

- List available versions

`apt list -a docker-ce`

Which will produce a list such as

```
docker-ce/stretch 5:18.09.0~3-0~debian-stretch armhf [upgradable from: 18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian]
docker-ce/stretch 18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian armhf
docker-ce/stretch,now 18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian armhf [installed,upgradable to: 5:18.09.0~3-0~debian-stretch]
docker-ce/stretch 18.03.1~ce-0~debian armhf
docker-ce/stretch 18.03.0~ce-0~debian armhf
docker-ce/stretch 17.12.1~ce-0~debian armhf
docker-ce/stretch 17.12.0~ce-0~debian armhf
```

- Select the version you want, for example

`sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian`